# Custom memo or text selection in Delphi Firemonkey for mobile?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, textselection

Is it possible to create a custom memo in firemonkey to implement things like syntax highlighting?

I wrote my own component on a Frame but it doesnt support mobile text selecting on android... Is there any way to create a custom memo or implement the native text selection into my own component on a TFrame?

What i mean is this:

[image]

Hold touch to select text, selected text gets hovered with blue background and on top the toolbar comes down.

Comment: But the TMemo already has this feature. Hold touch over the word and it Will get highlighted and buttons of copy, cut and paste Will appear.

Comment: But i need to customize the TMemo to implement Syntax highlighting or make my own control and implement this "selection" feature on my own...

Answer (score 0):

There is one full native android TMemo with the design you post available for Delphi. You can find the source code here: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/ (i gave the link because the code is too big to be post on SO)

You can also download the demo apk to see it in action:
https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/demos/ALFmxControls/Android/Release/ALFmxControls/bin/ALFmxControls.apk